# junit/spring properties not loading with application context

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit, maven

While running a junit test, I cannot get the application context to load properties from external properties files.

Given the following:

TestClass

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring/app-config.xml")
public class JdbcWatsonDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    JdbMyDao jdbcMyDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

app-config.xml

```
<util:properties id="aProperties" location="classpath:spring/a.properties" />
<util:properties id="bProperties" location="classpath:spring/b.properties" />

<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${oracle.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${oracle.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.password}"/>
</bean>
```

and the a.properties and b.properties files are in the same location as app-config.xml...

I've found that when running the test, the properties placeholders (the literal "${property}" )are what is being sent to the oracle server instead of the values in the properties files.

I've also tried using a bean configuration using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer instead of , but it still doesn't find/include properties.

I am using eclipse helios, spring 3.0.5, newest release m2eclipse and 4.4 junit.  I had to downgrade junit for a different maven/junit bug.

When published within tomcat, the properties are read and properly used.  I only see the problem when running a junit test.

Comment: Are you running the tests through a maven build or thorugh eclipse > run as > junit test?

Comment: eclipse>run as>junit test  

maven at this point is only managing dependencies.  I only brought it up because I've encountered another bug with it that had to do with build path order.

Answer (score 6):

According to your exception:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested
>   exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
>   Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017:
>   invalid username/password; logon
>   denied

Your probelm is NOT that the properties are not found,  if the properties are not found the exception would be something like `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: ... Could not resolve placeholder 'oracle.username'`

And this is because **you need to configure a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer instead of a 
PropertiesFactoryBean** (this is what util:properties does http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:spring/a.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:spring/a.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: But when I replace the placeholder text in the application context with the actual url/username/password values, the test runs.  The only thing I can think of is that the properties aren't properly read or found.  The [info] logs even state that the properties are loaded.  When this is published to a web container, it all works fine.  i.e. the properties are found, read and inserted properly. :(

Comment: The tests run with real values because they are read and assigned as string. The properties are found but they are not translated, i.e. "${foo.bar}" will be seen as a string not as a key for some value. Maybe the web container deployment involves a PlaceholderConfigurer in the full context. In your test you only have a minimal ContextConfig.

Comment: @Ralph I was trying to answer to camada's question (at least seems a question to me) from the first comment. But forgot to tag him

Answer (score 1):

You may separate your test configuration files, spring context, jbdc.properties, into *src/test/resources* dir to respect maven structure files.
To configure special **properties** files for test you have to define them in test spring application context using **propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer** as **Ralph** said.

Property files must be in *src/test/resources* and load them with the slash and file name **/a.properties**. Place the file in the same directory as the spring configuration file to load it.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/a.properties</value>
            <value>/a.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using maven.  It would help to know where you put the files.  By convention, the test version of the properties files should go in src/test/resources/ and production version in src/main/resources.  They should resolve automatically.

Comment: src/main/resources/spring/
    app-config.xml
    a.properties
    b.properties

I did not have them copied to src/test/resources.
I just copied them, cleaned and re-ran the test and it still doesn't work.

The actual exception thrown is:
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

If I hard code the values in the xml file, it works, but still won't read the prop files.

Answer (score -1):

I gave up.  I downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse 3.6 for Java EE and followed the springsource tool suite installation instuctions via the update site method.

I imported my project to the new environment with a new workspace and everythign works just fine.

I'll chalk it up to eclipse gnomes.

Comment: giving up and redoing thing is the last thing to do. This is not a solution to a question.